# How to jump a new line after author name in reference list with IEEEtran by using BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am writing a journal paper, and I need to make a reference list as

[image]

In my reference list after author name, I want to pass a new line and indent for 1 cm. After every article name or book name, I want to pass a new line.

I am using IEEEtran document style and Bibtex. I do not know how to change my reference format like in the photo. Can anyone help me about it?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{IEEEtran} 

\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb,dsfont}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
I want to cite this paper \cite{manwell2010wind}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

My bibtex ;

```
@book{manwell2010wind,
  title={Wind energy explained: theory, design and application},
  author={Manwell, James F and McGowan, Jon G and Rogers, Anthony L},
  year={2010},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable code you have so far ...

Comment: If I understand your requirements, you need a line break both after the author block *and* after the title block. Please confirm. And, does this requirement apply solely to entries of type `@article` and `@book`, or does it apply to all entry types? Incidentally, which bibliography style do you employ at present?

Comment: How should authors' names be formatted? For pieces with two or more authors, should the names of all authors be inverted (i.e., surname before given-name initials), or should the inversion apply only to the first author?

Comment: It applies to all entry types. My bibliography style is IEEEtran. Author name must be surname, and initials for all authors.

Comment: @Mico For all entry types, it should be like
Author Surname, Initials(Name) 
\newline and 1cm intent -title 
\newline and the same intent with the previous line -rest of information.

Comment: A general comment: Since you're writing a paper for a journal, and since the journal's formatting requirements for bibliographies are rather unusual (to put it mildly!!), it's really the journal's job to provide a suitable bibliography style (bst) file that implements these quirky formatting requirements. Have you checked the journal's website for a downloadable bst file? Have you contacted the journal's editorial staff directly and asked them for a suitable bst file? Can you at least provide a link to a web page of the journal that lists all formatting requirements for bibliographies?